# Why the `position: absolute` children not honour their relative parent?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a card which contains an image and some texts. The text should be put over the image. So I put all of them in a `.container` which has `position: relative` with themselves set to `position: absolute`.

**For the text:**

- the 1st part of the text sits at the left side with the wrapper `.row-start`, one by one in a row
- the 2nd part of the text sits at the right side with the wrapper `.row-end`
- of course both within the container

**Html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Color-blue.JPG"/>

            <div class="row-start">
                <p>Attr 1</p>
                <p>Attr 2</p>
            </div>

            <div class="row-end">
                <p>Attr 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Css:**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 15em;
}

.container img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.row-start {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.row-end {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
}
```

**What's the problem** 
What confuse me is that it seems `.row-start` can work while `.row-end` doesn't honor its `.container` parent at all. And it will be placed outside the `.container` div and from the right side of the page (so it honors the 
 `<html>` tag?)

What am I missing or doing something wrong here?
And any best practice for doing this? Thanks

Comment: `.row-end` _is_ positioned from the right edge of the container. Maybe your expectation of how wide the container is, is simply wrong? Use your browser dev tools, or give it a background color, to verify that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container element is a block, so it's size it's the size of the screen. I have added a background: red to your container so I can show you what i mean

You can see it on this pluckr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/QdsaqIU5X7xYX4UXksT9?p=preview

```
.container {
          position: relative;
          background: red;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! But after I add a width to the `.container`, the `.row-start` and `.row-end` children not be placed within the `.container`. Why?

Comment: They should. If you mean that they are below, you also need to add a top:0 to all the absolute positioned elements.

Here is an update version of the plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/xOafgI2yNsfJEAgAIYMA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Your `.container` DIV doesn't have a width definition, so it's 100% wide, i.e. full width (of its parent / in this example of the window). The height is 15 em, which apparently is more than the height of the image.
So your absolute DIVs *are* positioned in relation to the `.container`, but that container is larger than you apparently think it is - the image only covers part of the container div.

To change that, you can define a width for the container, and 100% width or the image.

Comment: Thanks! But after I add a width to the `.container`, the `.row-start` and `.row-end` children not be placed within the `.container`. I followed the above suggestion to add a `background` property, seems they are all outside the `.container` div. Why?